# Comparison of two tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, compare

I have two tables. One table (table1) has 28500 rows and the another (table2) has 17450 rows.
I would like to compare these tables and find rows that do not exist in table1.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM table2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: Doesn't your query work...

Comment: @ahmadalbayati OP has not describe that OP is using PHP or not.

Comment: @Broken Heart so i may not post my possible answer which is in PHP

Comment: Are you sure that ID is available in both table ?

Comment: @JDeveloper , if ID was not available the query provided by the OP would not be using it.

Comment: I made a tool which generates the ALTER statements to make the second table the same as the first one,if somebody is interested( still alpha) http://www.tablediff.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` link two table starting by table1, if table2 has no linked row all fields of table2 will be null. So, if you put in your `WHERE` condition table2.id is null, you get only rows in table1 not existing in table2

Comment: what this means SELECT table1.*

Comment: All fields of table1

Comment: well, ill be damn. it really works! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this by doing a left outer join and checking for all rows that don't exist.
Try the following depending on if you want to find values not existent from table1 in table2 or table2 in table1.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table2.id IS NULL;


SELECT *
FROM table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table2.id IS NULL;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9390/8

Comment: table2.id = NULL is not correct, please use IS NULL when you compare a field with a NULL value

Answer (score 2):

well, if you want the answer in PHP, then here is it:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='$id'");
    $check=mysql_num_rows($sql2);
    if($check==0)
    {
        echo $id." is not in table1<br>";
    }
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: This is a bad approach as if you have thousands of rows in table1 you will iterate over each one when running query of table2. It is extremely not efficient

Comment: True. Tells alot about me 5 years ago :D

Comment: Hahah... you are right, I am also feels like that when looking back at my previously written code. It means we are growing in our skills ;)

Comment: Yea, we are :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table2 
LEFT JOIN 
    table1
ON 
    table2.primary_key = table1 .primary_key
WHERE 
    table1 .primary_key IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare 2 tables by all columns (full compare, not just by single specific column like ID) you can use this approach:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM
 (
   SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3
   FROM t1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t2.column1, t2.column2, t2.column3
   FROM t2
)  t
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY column3
```

Based on example from: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
where id not in (
    SELECT table2.id
    FROM table2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1
    ON (
        table1.id = table2.id 
        and table1.col1 = table2.col1 
        and table1.col2 = table2.col2
        ...
    )
)
```

there **table1** have more rows than **table2**